# Alternative to Content Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

As it stands, Google Chrome extensions can fire content scripts on a page when it is loaded.

Would there be a way to inject a script into the page before it has loaded? It would be similar to a content script except it fires when a page has been requested, instead of waiting for it to load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked out the `run_at` property of content scripts?

> Optional. Controls when the files in js are injected. Can be "document_start", "document_end", or "document_idle". Defaults to "document_idle". 
>   
>    In the case of "document_start", the files are injected after any files from css, but **before any other DOM is constructed or any other script is run.**
>   [...]

<sup>Source: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad google already had the option and so that I didnt first look to the developers page.